# Relational algebra - select (select)

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Suppose I have a relation `map` called `M` with `from` and `to`.

I want to find all rooms that can be accessed with 1 intermediate room. Would the following lines be correct?

```
P = πTo (σFrom='Vestibule'(M)) 
X = P U πTo (σFrom=P(M))

X = πTo (σFrom= (σFrom='Vestibule'(M)) (M))
```

In other words, can I use the outcome of a select in another select, or do I have to use a product?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right, you need a inner query or nested queries into inside

following link explains logic of inner and outer queries it may help you.

http://www.codecandle.com/articles/sql/subqueries/sql-subquery.html